# Using sed command to replace config file with comment in linux terminal

Tags: sed

I know a little about sed. In /etc/nanorc I got bunch of settings with comments (eg:).

```
#bind ^K setting 1
#bind ^F whereis all
#bind ^J setting 3
```

So, I want to comment out only this setting to enable key CTRL+D in nano:

```
#bind ^F whereis all
```

I tried this but seems it doesn't work:

```
sed -ri "s/#bind ^F whereis all.*$/\bind ^F whereis all/" /etc/nanorc
```

Seriously, I don't know how to go with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting out one line is much easier with a simple text editor, but regardless...

Your command doesn't work because `^` is a special regexp character, meaning "start of the line" (when not between `[` and `]`). So your regexp will never match, because you expect the start of the line to be in the middle of the line. Also, you escape the `b` character in the replacement, which is not needed. Use this instead:

```
sed -ri "s/#bind \\^F whereis all.*$/bind ^F whereis all/" /etc/nanorc
```